# How to add a button on the title bar in Kivy

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

I am making an application. In my design I am planning to add a tabbed panel that is integrated into the title bar just like iCal application. Is there anyway to make this happen with kivy? Thanks in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6IKv.jpg)

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, What did you try? what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.tabbedpanel.html

Comment: I am trying to add a tabbed panel into the title bar just like the iCal application is there any way to make that happen?